# Import DBF or Excel file into SQL Server with dynamic column mapping using asp.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, asp.net-4.0, dbf

Recently, I've been importing a DBF file of approx 50 to 250 millions records with discrete columns structure into database table.

Suppose I'm having an database table "RawUpload" which consists of 68 columns to save uploaded details. This database Table structure is same for dbase/Excel file for unMapped columns. Consider a case where dbase File A1 has column name 'TrxnNo' and in another File A2 has column name 'TrxnNum' Or 'TradeNo' which alternately mapped to the database table column TransactionNumber nvarchar(255). Similarly, their are approx. 10 to 30 column in files which can changed frequently. It's hard to track them, so i wanted to go with dynamic column Mapping with database table at runtime.

To accomplish this task I've tried following cases :

1. Using **SSIS package** but not able to do with dynamic column structure.
2. Using `SqlBulkCopy` which taking more time to complete and even results to timeout and application hang state.
3. Using **DTS (Interop.DTS) package** works fine but fails for huge records.

Now my questions here is: which is the fastest way to import such big files into a SQL Server table with dynamic column mapping which will work for large data ?

Thanks

Comment: By dynamic column mapping do you mean there are multiple tables, each with a different design?  When you say *work in all scenarios* what do you mean?  That is quite broad and therefore hard to answer.  Can you provide specific scenarios instead?

Comment: @destination-data please check some upload info scenario added.